# Excessive SFTP CPU usage with chroot enabled when using the official Docker repository

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, docker, sftp

I have a fairly niche problem involving Docker, Fedora 37, and a 500M+ pull SFTP image, `atmoz/sftp`.

I installed Docker from the official repository, instead of Fedora's, and when I try to log into the SFTP server, the container uses 100% of one CPU core. After a minute or two, it finally logs in and I get the `sftp>` prompt.

**Start the SFTP server**

```
docker container run \
--interactive \
--tty \
--rm \
--name sftp-cpu-problem-debug \
--publish 2222:22 \
--env SFTP_USERS=cpuproblem:123:::IN \
atmoz/sftp:alpine

# You might have to kill it from a separate session using docker kill sftp-cpu-problem-debug
```

**Try to log in** (in a separate terminal session)

```
sftp -P 2222 -oLogLevel=DEBUG3 cpuproblem@localhost
# Password is 123
```

I tried to start the SSH daemon with DEBUG3 logging as well, but the log entries were identical to the ones where it worked without the CPU issue.

When I removed the `ChrootDirectory %h` line from the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file in the container, it logged in without issue even when using the official Docker packages. Of course, this disables chroot.

The following attempts all resulted in a working SFTP container where I could log in without the CPU issue.

- Use Podman instead of Docker to start a container using the same image, with the default, chroot enabled SFTP config.
- Use the `moby-engine` package from the Fedora repositories, instead of the official Docker packages from the Docker repositories.
- Use the official Docker repository packages on Debian, in WSL2.

This seems like some sort of Fedora configuration problem, because the same version worked on Debian, and the Fedora package (which is only a minor version older) also worked.

- What does the Fedora `moby-engine` package configure that the official Docker packages don't?

  - This might not be relevant, but this reminds me when a Spring Java app started up slow, because Spring Security was starved for entropy, and didn't use `/dev/urandom`.
  - It's such a strange corner case.

    - What is the SSH daemon trying to calculate, just before giving me the SFTP prompt?
    - Why does disabling chroot solve it?
    - Why isn't this a problem on Debian?
- I tried running with SELinux set to permissive, and also with `--privileged`, but it still had the CPU problem.
- I tried manually updating OpenSSH in the container, but that didn't help either.

Comment: You might want to run sudo perf top -a to figure out where your CPU core spins.

Comment: The two top entries are `[k] __entry_text_start` and `[k] exit_to_user_mode_prepare`. Here are the top entries: https://pastebin.com/bmui3Ani

Comment: Uhh that looks like musl trouble. Could you try with an image that's not based on Alpine?

Comment: Also, I can't really tell, but maybe adding -g to the perf invocation helps figure out who calls what. To me, this looks like a userland process using the musl libc going haywire while spinning on a file for some reason.

Comment: I tried with the Debian image, but the host has a 6.x kernel, and the Debian 11 container only had packages for 5.xx `perf`. With that said, the Alpine based version still worked on a Debian host. This is a snapshot from the Alpine container with -g: https://pastebin.com/8XRTAyhm

From the outside, perf showed a lot of `[k] __seccomp_filter` calls.

Comment: Ah you should just run perf in the host! Seccomp filter in perf: interesting, but I don't know how to interpret. Might or might not be relevant.

Comment: This is what the Debian container looked like from the host: https://imgur.com/a/gzyalch
(I couldn't copy the text from the terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue today, and after an `strace` and some searching, I found the following blog post by Alexandru Scvorțov:

**[56. Debugging a 12 minute hang after SFTP login](https://scvalex.net/posts/56/)**

You should definitely read it, but in short, OpenSSH uses a BSD-specific syscall that closes all file descriptors larger than a given integer. This syscall is not available in Linux, so the fallback implementation calls `close()` on every candidate file descriptor up to the system limit.

The post goes into more details that may be helpful to working around this issue.